# Encrypt=false in SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup Azure pipeline task

Tags: sql-server, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I need to execute a simple sql instruction on a DB hosted on an Azure VM.

I'm able to create a DB on that machine with an SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup task using TaskType: 'dacpac' and TargetMethod: 'connectionString', but i'm unable to connect to the DB using a TaskType: 'sqlInline'.

This is the yaml snippet:

```
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
  TaskType: 'sqlInline'
  InlineSql: 'sql command'
  ServerName: 'serverUrl'
  DatabaseName: 'db_name'
  AuthScheme: 'sqlServerAuthentication'
  SqlUsername: 'username'
  SqlPassword: $(DATABASE_PASSWORD)
```

But i get the error:

```
##[error]A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
```

Now, i know that this has something to do with Server side encryption, in the connection string i use when i create the DB with a dacpac file i have the option "Encrypt=False".

I've tried to pass this option to the task using AdditionalArguments or SqlAdditionalArguments but i didn't achieve anything.

Does anyone know how can i pass that parameter to the task without using a connection string?

Comment: Add `TrustServerCertificate=true` to the connection string.

Comment: I can't use the connection string when the task type is sqlInLine.. I tried but it is not accepted. If it were I would use "encrypt=false", it is enough

Comment: According to the task introduce of [SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines), the `ConnectionString` is required only when `TaskType = dacpac` and `TargetMethod = connectionString`. So, in this task, you cannot add the `ConnectionString` when the `TaskType` is '`sqlInline`'.

Comment: yes, that's what i meant, that's why i need an alternative since i have to use inline sql